# How to warp a group of points in a grid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, grids

[image]

Hi All,

I need some guidance on how to properly warp a group of dots.  I tried using the lower arc tool as well as the upper arc tool but it still need a lot of manual tweaking.

I'm also thinking of group each row and warping them manually but that will be very tedious since we are talking about 100,000 dots.

Another option is to use those cyan lines as guides to plot the dots but those existing dots have their unique layer / class id names.  If I go this route, I'll have to manually name 100,000 layers.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Does it need to be precisely the same amount of dots like it exists now? Would it be an option to re-create them using a brush?

Comment: Hi @Luciano Those dots represent the seats in the stadium and re creating them is tedious because I'll have to manually add their names in the layer panel.  These dots carry class id's which will be needed for development / coding.

Comment: Scaling from the top right, then shearing worked well at least.  Had to shear individual rows to make them precise as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a custom brush, applied to your rings/grid is probably the way to go, if you can't figure out a way to do it in the appearance palette using Transform.

Answer (score 0):

Are the seat rows concentric circles?
I think you're going to have to start over.
Use the polar grid tool (under the line tool button). Don't drag/draw one, click on art board with polar grid tool selected and fill in fields: radial dividers: none, Concentric circle dividers: as many as you need for your rows of seats.

Center the mesh in the stadium or at the focal point of the seat rows. Preview the mesh so each line is on a row of seats and the same amount of curved.

Apply dashed line to the stroke of the lines, 50% radius, curved corners and adjust gaps until 1 dot is on each seat. Adjust size and gaps of the dots so they are more seat shaped if you want.

Erase the dots you don't need. Reapply your data to each seat. The whole section of seats/dots can be grouped, rotated and used in another part of the stadium.

Comment: Woops I meant polar grid tool, not radial mesh.

Comment: Hi Webstarian, you can edit your own answer by clicking the [edit] button below it. Please also pay some attention to formatting you answers. Most are solid blocks of text, which doesn't read so well. Thanks for your time and effort and keep contributing!

Comment: Hi PieBie, thanks for the info. I will properly format my contributions now. I use Enter to go to a new line in the text editor, but those breaks are removed in the output. I will put double spaces now to preserve paragraphs and empty lines.

Comment: No problem at all. Just take a minute to read through the formatting info on the right of the answers box and you'll have the basics straight away. Any problem you might have, you can always ping us or find us in [chat].

Answer (score 0):

You could easily just apply a dashed stroke to a series of circles or ellipses.....

[image]

When done, expand and delete what you don't want.